# How to extract the forcasted from a timeseries,convert to dataframe and do a validation with the test data

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to do a daily forecast.However i need to pull out the forecast in a data frame.
But i am not able to check with my test data for validation and finally combine with the actual vs
the forecast and besides the show the forecast too in a data frame.Below the train data:

```
> dput(x<-AAMS%>%select(diffdays))
                        structure(list(diffdays = c(87, 55, 44, 38.5, 29.5, 29.33333333, 
                        29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 25, 24, 22.66666667, 22.57142857, 22.33333333, 
                        21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 20.75, 20.66666667, 20.66666667, 18, 18, 17.75, 
                        17.66666667, 17, 17, 16.8, 16.6, 16.5, 16.33333333, 16, 16, 15.57142857, 
                        15.33333333, 15.33333333, 15.25, 15, 14.33333333, 14.33333333, 
                        14, 13.8, 13.5, 12.75, 12.57142857, 12.33333333, 12, 11.5, 11.5, 
                        11.41666667, 11.33333333, 11.33333333, 11.33333333, 11.125, 11, 
                        11, 10.8, 10.8, 10.66666667, 10.5, 10.42857143, 10.33333333, 
                        10.25, 10, 10, 9.5, 9.384615385, 9.25, 9.25, 9.166666667, 9, 
                        8.8, 8.75, 8.666666667, 8.666666667, 8.5, 8.333333333, 8, 8, 
                        7.833333333, 7.666666667, 7.333333333, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6.666666667, 
                        6.5, 6.333333333, 6, 6, 5.833333333, 5.75, 5.571428571, 5.5, 
                        5.4, 5, 5, 5, 4.666666667, 4.666666667, 4.5, 4.333333333, 4.166666667, 
                        4, 4, 3.75, 3.5, 3.4, 3.333333333, 3.333333333, 3.25, 3, 3, 3, 
                        3, 2.666666667, 2.666666667, 2.5, 2.416666667, 2.375, 2.333333333, 
                        2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.2, 2.166666667, 2.125, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.846153846, 
                        1.666666667, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.25, 1.2, 1.142857143, 1.142857143, 
                        1.142857143, 1.125, 1, 1, 1, 0.75, 0.666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 
                        0.4, 48, 38, 31, 28, 27.81884058, 26.12, 25.59090909, 25.33333333, 
                        25, 24.75, 24.45128205, 24.125, 24, 23.4375, 23.35714286, 23.14166667, 
                        23, 23, 22.65497076, 22.6, 22.546875, 22.45833333, 22.35789474, 
                        22.1875, 22.16666667, 21.85714286, 21.75, 21.5, 21.33333333, 
                        21.33333333, 21.28125, 21.25, 21, 20.14285714, 19.90909091, 19.55, 
                        19.51851852, 19.38333333, 19.25, 19, 18.86805556, 18.85714286, 
                        18.5, 18.46153846, 18.33333333, 18, 18, 17.93, 17.86666667, 17.63888889, 
                        17.125, 17, 17, 16.95833333, 16.88888889, 16.88333333, 16.78571429, 
                        16.60714286, 16.60238095, 16.21127451, 16, 15.93333333, 15.65833333, 
                        15.61904762, 15.58333333, 15.54545455, 15.45454545, 15.2, 15.14980695, 
                        15, 15, 14.83333333, 14.8, 14.59803922, 14.53968254, 14.53333333, 
                        14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.42592593, 14.31578947, 14.25, 14.2, 14.02272727, 
                        14.02164502, 14, 13.86206897, 13.83333333, 13.75, 13.61111111, 
                        13.58333333, 13.55555556, 13.5, 13.5, 13.5, 13.3, 13.25892857, 
                        13.25, 13.1, 12.9047619, 12.8125, 12.78472222, 12.75, 12.72222222, 
                        12.71428571, 12.64285714, 12.57142857, 12.4375, 12.33333333, 
                        12.25862069, 12.22058824, 12.18181818, 12.04, 11.92857143, 11.92058824, 
                        11.91666667, 11.77777778, 11.77777778, 11.74074074, 11.625, 11.60714286, 
                        11.6, 11.57142857, 11.55555556, 11.5, 11.45454545, 11.2962963, 
                        11.28571429, 11.25, 11.22222222, 11.15, 11, 10.96703297, 10.91979167, 
                        10.75, 10.5862069, 10.5, 10.5, 10.41666667, 10.41666667, 10.4, 
                        10.33333333, 10.30555556, 10.16964286, 10.15416667, 10, 10, 10, 
                        10, 9.888888889, 9.75, 9.642857143, 9.6, 9.583333333, 9.5, 9.380555556, 
                        9.357142857, 9.333333333, 9.333333333, 9.25, 9.2, 9.19047619, 
                        9.166666667, 9.123655914, 9.083333333, 9.05, 9.020833333, 9, 
                        9, 9, 8.944444444, 8.9375, 8.916666667, 8.888888889, 8.857142857, 
                        8.777777778, 8.6875, 8.666666667, 8.666666667, 8.6, 8.5625, 8.5, 
                        8.380952381, 8.375, 8.357142857, 8.29, 8.285714286, 8.203703704, 
                        8.2, 8, 8, 8, 7.875, 7.8125, 7.8, 7.787037037, 7.75, 7.666666667, 
                        7.645833333, 7.6, 7.592592593, 7.5, 7.428571429, 7.366666667, 
                        7.25, 7.223684211, 7.2, 7.166666667, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6.833333333, 
                        6.820512821, 6.75, 6.733333333, 6.7, 6.666666667, 6.6, 6.5625, 
                        6.5, 6.454545455, 6.4, 6.390625, 6.388888889, 6.333333333, 6.285714286, 
                        6.221428571, 6.2, 6.2, 6.192307692, 6.0625, 6, 6, 5.857142857, 
                        5.833333333, 5.826086957, 5.75, 5.727272727, 5.72, 5.666666667, 
                        5.666666667, 5.628571429, 5.625, 5.604166667, 5.6, 5.444444444, 
                        5.395833333, 5.285714286, 5.281333333, 5.235294118, 5, 5, 4.990740741, 
                        4.925925926, 4.75, 4.696969697, 4.666666667, 4.666666667, 4.613636364, 
                        4.604166667, 4.571428571, 4.545454545, 4.371794872, 4.333333333, 
                        4.277777778, 4.167708333, 4.120689655, 4.111111111, 4.016666667, 
                        4, 4, 4, 4, 3.857142857, 3.833333333, 3.666666667, 3.65, 3.6, 
                        3.5, 3.43452381, 3.428571429, 3.375, 3.25, 3.2, 3.18, 3.142857143, 
                        3, 3, 3, 3, 2.8, 2.588235294, 2.583333333, 2.476666667, 2.35, 
                        2.266666667, 2.166666667, 2.166666667, 2.14, 2.125, 2, 2, 2, 
                        2, 2, 1.863636364, 1.84375, 1.833333333, 1.733333333, 1.625, 
                        1.6, 1.6, 1.166666667, 1.15, 1, 0.714285714, 0.666666667, 60.5, 
                        40.125, 38.76190476, 37.95238095, 36.83333333, 33.66666667, 33.66666667, 
                        33.16666667, 32.14285714, 32.13055556, 31.44444444, 31.16666667, 
                        29.94285714, 29.33333333, 29.3125, 26.24074074, 26.17647059, 
                        25.87719298, 25.46401515, 23.76388889, 22.03703704, 22, 21.8015873, 
                        21.5877193, 20.85294118, 20.47916667, 20.36956522, 20, 18.73333333, 
                        18.45833333, 18.42857143, 18.38157895, 17.5, 17.04166667, 16.23508772, 
                        15.97916667, 15.9, 15.75238095, 15.2, 15.14285714, 14.96296296, 
                        14.4, 14.02173913, 13.9, 13, 13, 12.875, 12.71428571, 12.09722222, 
                        11.45833333, 10.625, 10.13333333, 10.02173913, 9.928571429, 9.855555556, 
                        9.666666667, 9.55, 9.5, 9.5, 9.333333333, 8.8, 8.4375, 8.166666667, 
                        7.7, 7.6875, 7.6, 7.461538462, 7.291666667, 7.090909091, 6.527777778, 
                        6.4, 6.333333333, 6, 5.9375, 5.916666667, 5.666666667, 5.153846154, 
                        5.142857143, 4.952380952, 4.935483871, 4.785714286, 4.075757576, 
                        3.8, 3.285714286, 3.285714286, 2.781666667, 2.384057971, 2.366666667, 
                        1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -561L))
```

Below is the test data:

```
> dput(v<-validation%>%select(diffdays))
                        structure(list(diffdays = c(45, 41, 33.33333333, 31.2, 30.3, 
                        29.83333333, 28.88888889, 28.5, 28.24444444, 28, 25.5, 25.35, 
                        24.66666667, 24, 24, 22.75, 21.28, 21, 20.66666667, 19, 18, 18, 
                        17.33333333, 16, 15, 14.90909091, 14.5, 14, 13.48611111, 13.33333333, 
                        13, 12.75, 12.08333333, 11.5, 11.47916667, 10.53968254, 10, 10, 
                        10, 9.833333333, 9.75, 9.666666667, 9, 8.472222222, 8.333333333, 
                        7.333333333, 7.229166667, 7.111111111, 7, 6.857142857, 6.375, 
                        6, 5, 4.666666667, 4.438596491, 4.125, 4.055555556, 3, 2.5, 2.333333333, 
                        1.333333333, 1, 0.75)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                        -63L))
```

The below code is for the test data

```
test <- msts(v, seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25))
```

The code below the forecasting code:

```
 y <- ts(x, frequency=7)
                    fit <- ets(y)
                    fc <- forecast(fit)
                    plot(fc)
                    y <- msts(x, seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25))
                    fit <- tbats(y)
                    fc <- forecast(fit)
                    plot(fc)
                    y <- ts(x, frequency=7)
                    z <- fourier(ts(x, frequency=365.25), K=5)
                    zf <- fourier(ts(x, frequency=365.25), K=5, h=100)
                    fit <- auto.arima(y, xreg=z, seasonal=FALSE)
                    fc <- forecast(fit, xreg=zf, h=100)
                    plot(fc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the forecast using `fc$mean` or `as.data.frame(fc$mean)`.

Pay attention to the forecast horizon as test and forecast should have the same
length. In your case, the test object has 63 observations, while you perform a forecast for the next 100 periods.

For validation purposes, you can use `forecast::accuracy`.

Comment: As the forecasted is in a time series, i would like to combine with the actual data along with the forecasted values in a dataframe. can you please suggest. Besides i want to do a validation test with the test data to check how accurate is my forcaste?